# Android Application subclass constantly generates forceclose

Tags: android, android-manifest

Hi i've found a example on this site on how to make a subclass of the application for android.

I've created this code

```
package mensand.test;
class TestApp extends android.app.Application {

}
```

Added this line to the manifest

```
android:name="mensand.test.TestApp"
```

And when i run the app it's starts with a force close message.

When i remove the line from the manifest all runs ok

Greetings Andre Mens

Comment: Please include a complete stack trace of the exception.  To do so, in eclipse view the logcat view, or run adb logcat from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

Is that you have in that class? If yes then the problem is that you don't override the `onCreate()` method.

```
import android.os.Bundle;

class TestApp extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
        super.onCreate(bundle);
    }

}
```

That's what you've missed.

**EDIT:** Reviewing that code snippet again I realized that coping the code snippet of the OP isn't a good idea. I've missed that you are extending the `Application` class. In that case `onCreate()` won't take any parameters. What is it you are trying to achieve with extending the `Application` class?

Comment: Am I missing something? Surely the important thing is for the overridden onCreate() to call super.onCreate()... if the function isn't overridden then surely the base class version will get called anyway...

Comment: @Reuben Scratton: apparently I made a mistake when posting that code snippet up. See my edit. Thanks for commenting without your comment I would not have found that mistake.